# Create a cookie from an express server and send it back with the response

Tags: express, cookies

I'm playing and learning a bit **express** so I'm doing a Post to a specific route with some data related to my user and I'm trying to create a cookie from the expressJs server and send it back with the response. But unfortunately nothing happened. I'm testing the route with Postman and it's telling me:

```
No cookies were returned by the server
```

here's how i'm trying

```
  res.status(200).cookie('rememberme', '1', { expires: new Date(Date.now() + 900000), httpOnly: false }).send('Cookie sent...?');
```

I'm probably doing or missing something stupid, so what's wrong with that? Any ideas please..?

Comment: If you try the api in the browser, you should see the cookie

Comment: Indeed ! Do you know why i'm not able to check it with postman?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use older version of Postman, the one that runs in the browser, you would be able to see the cookie.

However, the new one doesn't run in the browser anymore, it becomes a seperate chrome app, so it doesn't read browser cookies anymore. In order to see the cookie, you will need to install the postman interceptor

[image]